# SQL Loop Over Name

Tags: sql, partition

I have:

```
TABLE1
    STUDENT CLASS   SCORE
    PAT A   14
    PAT A   10
    PAT B   13
    PAT B   20
    PAT C   11
    MARK    A   18
    MARK    A   13
    MARK    A   17
    MARK    A   10
    DAVIS   C   12
    JER A   15
    JER B   12
    JER C   20
    JER C   17
    BARB    C   14
    BARB    C   19
    BARB    C   11
    TOM A   18
    TOM A   12
    TOM B   16
    TOM B   12
```

and wish for to make:

```
STUDENT CLASS   AVERAGESCORE
PAT A   12
PAT B   16.5
PAT C   11
DAVIS   A   14.5
DAVIS   B   NA
DAVIS   C   NA
MARK    A   NA
MARK    B   NA
MARK    C   12
JER A   15
JER B   12
JER C   18.5
```

Which does this: for the STUDENT in the list, calculate AVERAGE(SCORE) BY CLASS AND STUDENT

I try this with no success:

```
LIST1 = PAT, MARK, DAVIS, JER
select STUDENT, CLASS, AVG(SCORE) OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENT, CLASS) AS AVERAGE_SCORE
from TABLE1
where STUDENT in LIST1
```

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Comment: this isn't a "partition" question, so that tag is irrelevant

Comment: is there a CLASS table?  how do you know which classes are valid to generate NA values if there are no scores?

Comment: Edit your question's sample data so the values come in proper columns!

Comment: You'll need to outer join with a distinct list of classes I think and then just aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

```
select student, class, avg(score)
from table1
where student in ('PAT', 'DAVIS', 'MARK', 'JER')
group by student, class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you first need a list of all class / student combinations, to which you can outer-join and then aggregate:

```
with c as (select distinct class from t),
s as (select Student from(values('PAT'),('MARK'),('DAVIS'),('JER'))s(Student)),
a as (select Student, Class from s cross join c)

select a.Student, a.Class, Avg(t.Score * 1.0) AverageScore
from a 
left join t on t.class = a.class and t.Student = a.Student
group by a.Student, a.Class
order by a.Student, a.Class;
```